# Trouble understanding how to create a grammar parse tree

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I'm starting an online Computer Science class called Advanced Programming Languages, and the book asks me to create a parse tree and generate a grammar from it.  Here are the exact instructions:

> To verify that a string of characters belongs to a language defined by a grammar, we must create a parse tree that shows that the string can be generated by the grammar.

```
<list> -> <item> , <list> | <item> 
<item> -> <left> <item> <right> | <left> <right>
<left> -> A| B | C 
<right> -> x | y | z
```

> Choose a string that is in this language and create a parse tree that demonstrates that your claim is true. Identify another string that contains some of these terminals symbols but is not in the language.

I think I know how to get started, but I keep getting confused by examples in the book and examples online.  Is there a general method to use when approaching this?

I began it this way:

```
            <list>
         /          \    
      <item>      <list>
    /    |    \
<left> <item> <right>
  |    /
  A  <left>
```

But I get confused on the next iterations of the `item`.  Any hints?

Comment: 1. OK, good, that makes a significant difference.  Now the question makes sense.  2. What does "next iterations of the `item` mean?  3. You're trying to show us an example parse tree, but what string is that supposed to correspond to?  It sounds like you're trying to start with a parse tree, expand it out, and then find a corresponding string.  If you're stuck with that, you might also want to try the reverse: pick a string that you know is in the grammar, and then try constructing a parse tree for it (run a standard parsing algorithm by hand, if need be).

Comment: @D.W. 1. Thanks!  2. (Please excuse my lack of understanding as this is new to me.)  I actually meant `list`, and I basically just assumed since it also appears in the production of `<list>` that it is a recursive call.  3. You're correct, that is what I was trying to do.  How can I pick a string that is in the grammar?

Comment: It's the standard way of doing a derivation with a context-free grammar.  Start with the start symbol (non-terminal), and apply productions until you get to a string that contains only terminals.  Any good textbook should have some explanation of productions or examples of grammars and production rules.

Comment: @D.W. is `A x`  a string in the grammar?

Comment: @D.W. ok, thanks for your help here.  Appreciate it

Comment: @D.W. just to make sure I'm on the correct track with my understanding; is the first line basically saying an `item` AND `list` produce a `list` OR just an `item`.  And the for `item` is it saying `<left>` AND `<item>` AND `<right>` produce an `<item>` OR `<left>` AND `<right>`?

Comment: @D.W. in other words, if I just use the OR portion of each production I can essentially have `<list> -> <item>` and then `<item> -> <left><right>` and can produce  `Ax` ?

Comment: It sounds like you really need more interactive assistance.  Unfortunately, this site is not well-suited for that.  I recommend that you find a tutor, teacher, or friend who knows this material and ask them.  This site is not a discussion forum and isn't intended for back-and-forths or interactive discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before expanding a grammar into a parse tree, we should first try to understand it at a higher level.

```
<list> -> <item> , <list> | <item> 
<item> -> <left> <item> <right> | <left> <right>
<left> -> A| B | C 
<right> -> x | y | z
```

First, `<list>` is a list of `<item>`, separated by commas if there are multiple ones.

Second, an `item` is either a pair of alphabets (the `left` is one of `A | B | C`; the `right` is one of `x | y | z`) or recursively, an `item` surrounded by such a pair.
Thus, an `<item>` is a word composed of, say $n$, upper-case alphabets from `A | B | C`, followed by the same number, $n$, of lower-case alphabets from `x | y | z`.

> ***$Q_1$:*** Choose a string that is in this language and create a parse tree that demonstrates that your claim is true.

`ABCxyz,ACyz` is in this language; can you generate a parse tree for it?

> ***$Q_2$:*** Identify another string that contains some of these terminals symbols but is not in the language.

`AyCz` is not in this language; can you explain why?

---

In addition, when you are searching for *any* string in a grammar by expanding the grammar into a parse tree, you can push the tree into its leaves as fast as you can, by choosing the *non-recursive* rules whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation!  I can generate the parse tree for the string you have.  It helped a lot when I drew out the parse tree and could visually see how the strings were being formed.  I generated the string `ABxy,CAzx` from this grammar, which basically doesn't expand `<item>` as far down as your string.  One more layer of expansion for `<item>` and I can generate your string.